# Why can't I do a comment ( /* like this one */ ) in PHP?

Tags: php

I just downloaded all the PHP's extensions, and this error popped off:

[image: This is the error]

And I did what the error says, and when I started coding, I wasn't able to do a comment with `/* This is a comment */`

[image]

Comment: As for the comment, you are trying to use a PHP comment in HTML - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640453/single-line-comment-in-html

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65753852/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do something like this:

```
<!-- Write your comments here -->
```

because you want to comment in an HTML file.